How to attach link to a text to Chatter post via Chatter rest API
I want to add a link to the chatter post and describe this with a text.
I am using below documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_requests_markup_begin_segment_input.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_requests_markup_end_segment_input.htm
Request URL: chatter/feed-elements/batch
Request Body:
{
"inputs": [
    {
        "richInput": {
            "subjectId": "{subjectId}",
            "body": {
                "messageSegments": [
                    {
                        "markupType": "Hyperlink",
                        "type": "MarkupBegin",
                        "altText": "describe link",
                        "url": "https://google.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "markupType": "Hyperlink",
                        "type": "MarkupEnd"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "feedElementType": "FeedItem"
        }
    }
]

}
Error:
{
"hasErrors": true,
"results": [
    {
        "result": [
            {
                "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD",
                "message": "The hyperlink text can&#39;t be null, empty, or contain only spaces."
            }
        ],
        "statusCode": 400
    }
]

}

The error is caused by the hyperlink text not correctly specified in the request body. To correctly add a hyperlink in a Chatter post, you can wrap the text you want to turn into a link with the MarkupBegin and MarkupEnd segments.
I have tried to post the same request to my org for the user and it works.
Request URL: https://tushar-jadav-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/chatter/feed-elements
Request Method: POST
Request Body:
{ 
   "feedElementType":"FeedItem",
   "subjectId":"0050o00000VjyR8AAJ",
   "body" : {
        "messageSegments" : [
                {
              "markupType": "Hyperlink",
              "type": "MarkupBegin",
              "url": "https://google.com"
            },
            {
              "type": "Text",
              "text": "describe link"
            },
            {
              "markupType": "Hyperlink",
              "type": "MarkupEnd"
            }
      ]
   }
}

In the request body subjected is a UserId. For more information refer to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/features_feeds_feed_elements.htm
Output:

